# How can I change graph line characters in `git log --graph` via command args?

Tags: git, logging, graph, zsh

Now:

```
*
|\
| *
| |\
| |/
|/|
* |
|\ \
```

Want to see:

```
•
├─╮
│ •
│ ├─╮
├─│─╯
• ╰─╮
├─╮ │
```

Characters I want to use:

`╭ ╮ ╯ ╰ │ • ─ ├`

[image]

---

- https://github.com/radare/radare2/issues/8586

Comment: May be using different git software lots of suggestions found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057564/pretty-git-branch-graphs#9074343

Answer (score 1):

Use specified interface for that, like tig:
https://github.com/jonas/tig